# Indexed View w Business Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexed-view

I have been tasked to create several 'views' on data that exists on our analytics server. These views are 'business logic' heavy, but will be referenced by potentially multiple tools, so we are trying to centralize the logic into the sql server.

In essence, we have two operating companies, so we select a bunch of stuff from a bunch of tables into a 'standard' format, including a few columns that use formulas/case statements to output something meaningful to the biz.

Each company has a view. Then there is a parent view that combines them with a union all. The two company specific views are maintained by different people, but the both sides have the same columns / definitions / etc.

I was hoping to create an indexed view on the unioned view to materialize it as we are having some performance issues in our end point analysis tool.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Done, thanks! Appreciate that!